# How to easily edit control file in deb package

Tags: debian, package-management, deb

Is there a way to easily edit control file in deb package. Doesn't matter on which system (Linux, Mac OS X etc.) Maybe someone knows a good script to make it automated?

Answer (score 10):

Check this out: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724
Just in case that thread ever gets deleted, I'll post a copy of the code here as well:

```
DEBFILE="$1"
TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/deb.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
OUTPUT=`basename "$DEBFILE" .deb`.modfied.deb

if [[ -e "$OUTPUT" ]]; then
  echo "$OUTPUT exists."
  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

dpkg-deb -x "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"
dpkg-deb --control "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN

if [[ ! -e "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control ]]; then
  echo DEBIAN/control not found.

  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

CONTROL="$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control

MOD=`stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"`
vi "$CONTROL"

if [[ "$MOD" == `stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"` ]]; then
  echo Not modfied.
else
  echo Building new deb...
  dpkg -b "$TMPDIR" "$OUTPUT"
fi

rm -r "$TMPDIR"
```

Change `vi` to any editor of choice. Save it as a shell script (i.e. `debcontrol.sh`), make it executable (`chmod +x`), and use the deb as first parameter (`./debcontrol.sh xxxxx.deb`)

Answer (score 5):

The script from the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724) needs a few changes to run.  Since my edit to the other post wasn't approved, here is my updated version.

```
#!/bin/bash
DEBFILE="$1"
TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/deb.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
OUTPUT=`basename "$DEBFILE" .deb`.modified.deb

if [[ -e "$OUTPUT" ]]; then
  echo "$OUTPUT exists."
  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

dpkg-deb -x "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"
dpkg-deb --control "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN

if [[ ! -e "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control ]]; then
  echo DEBIAN/control not found.

  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

CONTROL="$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control

MOD=`stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"`
sensible-editor "$CONTROL"

if [[ "$MOD" == `stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"` ]]; then
  echo Not modified.
else
  echo Building new deb...
  dpkg -b "$TMPDIR" "$OUTPUT"
fi

rm -r "$TMPDIR"
```

Save it as a shell script, make it executable (`chmod +x videbcontrol`), and run it like so:

```
fakeroot videbcontrol package.deb
```

It's important to use `fakeroot`, otherwise file ownership gets reset to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

The other method works well and should be the accepted answer. I'm writing this down because not using the dpkg tools might help understand how the deb format works (an `ar` archive with two `tar` members) and it avoids needing fakeroot which does not work on some architectures like mipsel.

```
ar x libc-bin_2.36-8_ppc64el.deb
unxz control.tar.xz # because tar --append does not work with compression
tar --to-stdout -xf control.tar ./postinst  > postinst
sensible-editor postinst # make edits to postinst
chmod +x postinst
tar --to-stdout -xf control.tar ./control > control
sensible-editor control # bump version in control file
tar --delete -f control.tar ./postinst ./control # avoid duplicate members
tar --append --owner=root --group=root -f control.tar ./postinst
xz control.tar
ar r test.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
```