# How to install Google Earth on Debian Stretch?

Tags: linux, debian, google-earth, stretch

after downloading from google the deb file I try:

```
dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

but it complains that lsb-core is missing. So I need that package, "which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package". 
It looks like lsb-core has been removed from Debian Stretch.

Any hints?

Comment: `lsb-core` is still available on Ubuntu (as at 15.04) and it may well install on Debian if you down-load the **.deb** file. You may also find [this link](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/03/install-google-earth-in-ubuntulinux.html) helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Debian dropped LSB support](https://lwn.net/Articles/658809/), so `lsb-core` it's not in Debian >= Stretch anymore.

### Update

As correctly noted by @tknv, some months after this answer a new `lsb-compat` has been made available. So the best solution to the problem is to install it:

```
sudo apt install lsb-compat
```

### Tampering way (deprecated):

To have it working you also could:

1. Modify the package metadata removing the `lsb-core` dependency
2. Ensure the presence of `ld-lsb` ELF linker (once provided by `lsb-core`)

To do so you can:

1. Follow the instructions already reported [here](https://superuser.com/questions/280370/how-to-easily-edit-control-file-in-deb-package)
2. Check the name of the ld-lsb ELF linker required (architecture dependent):

   ```
   ldd /opt/google/earth/free/googleearth-bin |grep ld
   ```
3. Using the information gathered in 2, manually create the symlink. For 64-bit architecture the command is:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
   ```

   For 32-bit architecture I *guess* the correct command would be:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux-x86.so.2 /lib/ld-lsb-x86.so.3
   ```

Comment: The 32-bit version is actually: `sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /lib/ld-lsb.so.3`

Answer (score 4):

It worked with my Debian Stretch. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-compat
```

Info about the [lsb-compat package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=lsb-compat)

Answer (score 0):

This is also the fix when bypassing the installer and extracting the deb. Then the very misleading error is:

```
bash: ./googleearth-bin: No such file or directory
```

It is not the google earth binary which is missing, but the specified loader ld-lsb-x86.so.3

Answer (score 0):

I am running Debian Stretch.
I downloaded `google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb`, and
I installed `lsb-compat` as described above, except `sudo` is not a command on my system.  Instead I used the command `su`, and supplied the password.

```
su
apt-get install lsb-compat
cd Downloads
dpkg google-earth-pro_stable_current_amd64.deb
```

I can run it from a command line with the command `google-earth-pro`.
But the view occupies just a tiny upper left corner of the available screen space.  It is not very usable at this point, but it is installed.